# Unable to build cordapp with accounts dependencies

Tags: corda

I was able to build a cordapp using Accounts by following the steps at https://github.com/corda/accounts.

This cordapp was building and running until 03/16/2020, but since 03/20/2020 I am seeing errors in my CI builds because https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-lib-dev/com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/accounts-contracts/1.0-RC04/accounts-contracts-1.0-RC04.jar cannot be accessed. I get a 409 response now, how can I resolve this?

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 409,
    "message" : "The repository 'corda-lib-dev' rejected the resolution of an artifact 'corda-lib-dev:com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/accounts-contracts/1.0-RC04/accounts-contracts-1.0-RC04.jar' due to conflict in the snapshot release handling policy."
  } ]
}
```

My build.gradle has

```
accounts_release_version = '1.0-RC04'
accounts_release_group = 'com.r3.corda.lib.accounts'
confidential_id_release_group = "com.r3.corda.lib.ci"
confidential_id_release_version = "1.0-RC03"

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-lib-dev' }
    maven { url 'http://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-lib' }
}
```

My local builds on my development environment work fine, I assume because I already have the jars in my .m2

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question, not just external links, as these may go stale, or just not be correct for your question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifactory configuration has been changed to enforce separation between release and snapshot repositories. `corda-lib-dev` is a snapshot repo and CorDapp developers should not be developing against these.

Releases and release candidates will be available in `corda-lib` going forward.

Kindly use `corda-lib`, and develop again release 1.0.

Comment: but the maven repositories in the question also has corda-lib added. still why did the error occur ?   i too have a same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The pom file with RC04 is set to return 409. I assume Corda's way to disallow use of RC04. May be RC03 is also the same. I just tried this today and saw the repository pom files.
Use "1.0" instead of  "1.0-RC03"